# How to delete an appended message in jquery after you have already appended once clicking the same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: 2ndpic][image: Picture for of what I have]I have looked through a lot of the already asked questions and cannot find it. I need the previous appended message to be deleted once you hit the submit button again. So this will let you choose your character that you type into the input field and then it will append a message bellow telling you that you choose x character. After that you can resubmit another character which I want, but I do not want the previous append to be there.

I tried to do a search function in javascript and if it was not equal to -1 then delete the first p in the div, but that did not work=/

Thanks for your help in advance.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Result</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/main.css'/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
          Chose your character (human, orc, elf) : <br><br><input id='text' type="text" name="mess" value="">
          <button id='button1' type="button" name="button" onclick="chooseChar()">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="box_holder"></div>
      <br><br>
      <button id='button2' type='button' name='button2' onclick="redirect()">Start Your Adventure</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button1').click(function(){
    var send = $("input[name=mess]").val();
    $('#box_holder').append('<p>'+ 'You have chosen your character to be: '+send+'</p>');
    });
    $('input').css("color","blue");


});

chooseChar = function () {
var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
var text = text.toLowerCase();
if(text == 'human') {
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button1').click(function(){
    var div = $("#box_holder p").val();
    var searchTerm = "You";
    var searchDiv = div.search(searchTerm);
    if (searchDiv != -1) {
      $('div p').first().remove();
    }
  });
});
  window.alert("HUMAN YOU ARE! (You may change your character at anytime)");
  return;
} else if (text == 'orc') {
  window.alert("ORC YOU ARE! (You may change your character at anytime)");
  return;
} else if (text == 'elf') {
window.alert("ELF YOU ARE !(You may change your character at anytime)");
return;
} else {
  window.alert("Start over! Please choose one of the characters above!");
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').remove();
  });
  return;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

});
};

redirect = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var url = text+".html";
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using append, try using html as follows

```
$('#box_holder').html('<p>'+ 'You have chosen your character to be: '+send+'</p>');
```

[Here is a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5QBSDnrGPUgTvdibmnFP?p=preview) to explain it a little better

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button1').click(function() {
    var send = $("input[name=mess]").val();
    $('#box_holder').html('<p>' + 'You have chosen your character to be: ' + send + '</p>');
  });
  $('input').css("color", "blue");


});

chooseChar = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
  text = text.toLowerCase();
  if (text == 'human') {
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#button1').click(function() {
        var div = $("#box_holder p").val();
        var searchTerm = "You";
        var searchDiv = div.search(searchTerm);
        if (searchDiv != -1) {
          $('div p').first().remove();
        }
      });
    });
    window.alert("HUMAN YOU ARE! (You may change your character at anytime)");
    return;
  } else if (text == 'orc') {
    window.alert("ORC YOU ARE! (You may change your character at anytime)");
    return;
  } else if (text == 'elf') {
    window.alert("ELF YOU ARE !(You may change your character at anytime)");
    return;
  } else {
    window.alert("Start over! Please choose one of the characters above!");
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('div').remove();
    });
    return;
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

  });
};

redirect = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var url = text + ".html";
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
    Chose your character (human, orc, elf) :
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="text" type="text" name="mess" value="" />
    <button id="button1" type="button" name="button" onclick="chooseChar()">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <br />
  <div id="box_holder"></div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="button2" type="button" name="button2" onclick="redirect()">Start Your Adventure</button>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to remember, the append() function appends the content on the selected component. The html() function replaces all content inside of it.

Hope it helps

Comment: What I want to happen is when someone types human it will say "You have chosen your character to be: human". Which that part is working. If I then type in elf I want it to say the say except for elf , but then also deleting the human statement before it.

Comment: If there is a way to do so in javascript that is also fine =] thank you for help!

Comment: I managed to do this. I think I know what you're trying to say so I'll add a Plunkr to the answer in a couple minutes

Comment: Let me know if the solution I just added is what you're looking for!

Comment: This still doesnt add a text line afterwords. So like under the input box and submit button I want it to add "you have chosen your character to be: human/orc/elf". Which like I said I have that working with the append. But then I want it to delete when I put in another input and be replaced. The html thing isnt adding any text below like I want.

Comment: I don't totally understand what you're trying to say. May be you can add an image or something. I'm sure I can help you a lot better when I know what you goal is.

Comment: Okay I posted a picture in the original post. It shows that I have text underneath and that was only there after I hit the submit button and but the text human into the input field. Now, when I type in elf and hit submit I want the word human to be replaced in that sentence or just have that whole line removed and it post the sentence with elf. If I hit submit as of now it will just add another line underneath saying the same thing except with elf.

Comment: Went ahead and added another pic to show you what happens if I just keep hitting submit.

Comment: If you want the whole line removed and posting the sentence with elf, that's what the Plunkr is doing. Every time you hit submit the line is deleted and a new one is added.

Comment: Weird I tried that a little bit ago and it didnt work, but now it does it just fine!! Thank you so much! Sorry for all the trouble!

Comment: No problem, you should mark the question as resolved! Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

So your variable send gets sent and then it clears out the input field with either of those functions

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#button1').click(function(){
  $('#box_holder').children('p').remove(); <===========
  or                                                  Either of these should work
  $('#box_holder').empty(); <===========================
  var send = $("input[name=mess]").val();
  $('#box_holder').append('<p>'+ 'You have chosen your character to be: '+send+'</p>');
});
$('input').css("color","blue");


});
```

Comment: Okay so I tried the first one and it did not have anything happen and the second one just showed "You have chosen your character to be:", but when I would type in human for example nothing would happen. What I want to happen is when someone types human it will say "You have chosen your character to be: human". Which that part is working. If I then type in elf I want it to say the say except for elf , but then also deleting the human statement before it.

Comment: If there is a way to do so in javascript that is also fine =] thank you for help!

Comment: Try the first one without the 'p' just:
$('#box_holder').children().remove();

Comment: Still isnt showing anything after the input field and submit button. So mine I have it already showing the text underneath when you hit submit.